PhpMailer returns 'Could not connect to SMTP Host' error
Below is my code to send the email to approver once the user has submitted the request. the email will be sent to approver for the first time, but, after multiple emails being sent to approver, ive got the Could not connect to SMTP Host error.
$resAdd = sqlsrv_query($conn, $queAdd) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));

 if ($resAdd) {

    // passing true in constructor enables exceptions in PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $emailBody = "This email is for testing only. Please ignore. Please check the link document. <a href = 'http://localhost/einv/v1/viewDet.php?variable=$refNum'><label>Link</label></a>";

        // Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // for detailed debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
          'ssl' => array(
          'verify_peer' => false,
          'verify_peer_name' => false,
          'allow_self_signed' => true
          )
          );
   
        $mail->Username = 'support_einv@outlook.com'; 
        $mail->Password = 'abc134'; 

        // Sender and recipient settings
        $mail->setFrom('support_einv@outlook.com', 'e-Inv Notification', 0);
        $mail->addAddress('user@outlook.com');

        // Setting the email content
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "[FOR TESTING, PLEASE IGNORE] Pending Approval : $refNum";
        $mail->Body = html_entity_decode($msg_body);

        $mail->Body = $emailBody;
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . print_r(error_get_last(), true);
        } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent';   
            $mail->smtpClose();
        }
   
   echo "<script type=text/javascript>";
   echo "alert('Your request submitted successfully.'),location.href='../viewDet.php?variable=$refNum'";
   echo "</script>";
 }

Any other issue that can be a cause for this error?
I've tried various solution, but none of it works. Some of the solution that ive tried:

check firewall
use $mail->Host = gethostbyname("smtp-mail.outlook.com");
include smtpClose()
enabled php.ini line - extension=php_openssl.dll


Have you tried $mail->Host  = 'smtp.office365.com';  and $mail->Port = 587;

If you check any other question here about PHPMailer, you will see it should generate much more debug error output than just "Could not connect to SMTP Host", maybe including more info about why it could not connect.  If you're not seeing more output, the next question you should ask yourself is why not?  And how do I get it?  Checking the PHPMailer docs there is a simple example which shows how to handle errors: to check $mail->ErrorInfo.  So, have you tried that?

While you say you've checked these things, you don't include any output from those checks. The most likely explanation is that your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP, especially on port 25. What happened when you did the checks from the troubleshooting guide? If that is the case, you won't get much debug output (since nothing happens), and you should increase the debug level to see low-level info with $mail->SMTPDebug = 4.

@Don'tPanic, im getting this error, Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp-mail.outlook.com:587 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. ). im only getting this error after sending several emails. but after around 1-2 hours, im able to send the email again.

@MalcolmInTheCenter hello, ive tried to change to $mail->Host  = 'smtp.office365.com'; and $mail->Port = 587;
but im still getting the same error : Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.office365.com:587 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. )

Outlook has diffferent SMTP settings and usually blocks any phpmail request. If you want phpmail to connect to the outlook SMTP you have to either change the SMTP settings to allow the From: mailer to be authorized. (You can dot thin in the Outlook settings itself)
Alternatively you can depend on a third party library to make this happen which doesn't use phpmailer.

None of this is correct. Outlook doesn't block PHPMailer, it's nothing to do with From settings because it's not getting that far, and changing to another library will not make any difference.

@Synchro I've been working with wordpress Outlook SMTP a long time and never had PHPmailer to connect to outlook, i've always had to use a different mailprovider.
Truth is PHPmailer is old, not as safe and outdated. It's best to use an alternative provider

You're just talking rubbish. I know because I'm the maintainer of PHPMailer.
